# New line within MathJAX

Tags: support, mathjax

$P(E) = \dfrac{\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...}{N!}$

How can I force the red onto the next line of the numerator?

Moreover, how can I add an empty line (ie double space) the numerator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\\` works:

$$P(E) = \dfrac{\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) }\\\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...}{N!}$$

`$$P(E) = \dfrac{\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) }\\\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...}{N!}$$`

Double line (using the non-breaking space character `~`):

$$P(E) = \dfrac{\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) }\\~\\\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...}{N!}$$

`$$P(E) = \dfrac{\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) }\\~\\\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...}{N!}$$`

---

Or use the `align` environment:

$$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{align}&\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ &\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{align}}{N!}$$

`$$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{align}&\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ &\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{align}}{N!}$$`

$$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{align}&\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ \\&\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{align}}{N!}$$

`$$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{align}&\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ \\&\color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{align}}{N!}$$`

Comment: NB. You should really use `\ldots` in place of `...`.

Comment: You might want to include a `multline` version as well. (IMHO it looks better than the `align`.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Many thanks. Upvoted. Can a new empty line (For double spacing) be forced with // or something other than `\align`? Please answer in your answer; I'd like to consolidate all content.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I can't get `multline` to work -- it looks hideously misaligned to me.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Maybe we have different aesthetic tastes in this matter.  I for one think that the "misalignment" is a good indicator that something has spanned more than one line.

Comment: @ArthurFischer To me, the expression isn't even properly lined up above the bar -- it's shifted to the right by some length. But indeed, my taste here is to have both lines start without indentation. In an `eqnarray`-type environment, I agree that indentation is helpful.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I think it has something to do with how `frac` works. In neither `align` nor `multline` is the formula centred above the bar.  It is perfectly "right-aligned" but not perfectly "left-aligned".  (Or at least this is how I am currently seeing it.)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Lord_Farin's options, I'll include one-and-a-half using `multline` (which he apparently does not favour).

`$$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{multline}\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ \color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{multline}}{N!}$$`

yields

> $$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{multline}\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ \color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{multline}}{N!}$$

Introducing a second `\\` at the obvious place results in

> $$P(E) = \dfrac{\begin{multline}\text{ 1 choice for C1 } \times ... \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k - 1) } \times \text{ 1 choice for C(k) } \\ \\ \color{red}{\times N} - k \text{ choices for C(N - k) }\times N - k - 1 \text{ choices for C(N - k - 1)} \times ...\end{multline}}{N!}$$

<sub>[It appears that some users will see some hideous monstrosity. Apologies.]</sub>

Comment: Here's how it looks to me: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ktVI.png). Do you still blame me for not including it?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yikes, that's horrible!  It actually looks quite pleasant [to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cs7J.png).  (And your examples don't look _that_ bad either.)

Comment: +1 on the basis of your screenshot. And thanks for exposing me to `multline`!

Comment: `multline` is intended for top-level use only (LaTeX prevents its use in other ways, but MathJax is not so picky).  It creates elements that try to be 100% wide, and that can cause it to overflow the fraction.  It appears that browsers differ on how they handle that.  In any case, this is not really valid LaTeX, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I've got the same result as Lord_Farin on Google Chrome.